# What's the default location of .feature files on cucumber-jvm?

Tags: cucumber

I can't find in the documentation where cucumber-jvm looks for .feature files.

I created a project from the cucumber-jvm maven archetype and mvn test find the sample feature files without problems but there is no configuration.

Then I created a project from there maven project archetype, and mvn test doesn't find a feature file I created. And would like to understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Cucumber-JUnit. Create an empty class that uses the Cucumber JUnit runner.

```
package com.example;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

This will execute all scenarios in same package as the runner (`com.example`), by default glue code is also assumed to be in the same package. The @CucumberOptions can be used to provide additional configuration to the runner.

So if you're using maven then you put your features in `/src/test/resources/com/example/`.

From: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit

Comment: Thanks @mpkorstanje it seems that I'm also a newbie with JUnit, the issue was JUnit not reading my runner because the class didn't have the Test suffix, added that and moved the .feature to the correct package, and it was found.